# how to update with a foreign key field that also has a foreign key field

Tags: python-3.x, django

I have three sample models below:

```
Class User(Model):
    ...some other fields
    receiving_info = OnetoOneField('ReceivingInfo')

Class ReceivingInfo(Model):
    ...other fields
    receiving_address = OnetoOneField('Address')
    
Class Address(Model):
    street = CharField(max_length=100)
    house_number = CharField(max_length=100)
    city = CharField(max_length=200)
```

I am trying to update them below using this:

```
address = Address(
   street='new st',
   house_number='new number',
   city='new city'
)

user = User.objects.get(id=id)
user.receiving_info.receiving_address = address
user.save()
```

but somehow it doesn't work, any ideas how to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to *save* the address first, otherwise it has no primary key, and you thus can not link to it:

```
address = Address(
   street='new st',
   house_number='new number',
   city='new city'
)
address.save()

user = User.objects.get(id=id)
receiving_info = user.receiving_info
receiving_info.receiving_address = address
receiving_info.save()
```

You should also save the `receiving_info` object, not the `user`, since that object remains unchanged.

You can however make this more efficient, and reduce the number of queries with one by retrieving the `ReceivingInfo` directly:

```
address = Address.objects.create(
   street='new st',
   house_number='new number',
   city='new city'
)

receiving_info = ReceivingInfo.objects.get(user__id=id)
receiving_info.receiving_address = address
receiving_info.save()
```

I'm also not entirely sure why you have a `ReceivingInfo` model in the first place. It looks like it has not much "added value", and it only makes querying more complicated. If it thus only groups some info, it still might be better to save this under the `User` model.